# R: Back-referencing data frame in `with` expression

Tags: r, scope

Is there a way to back-reference the scope in a `with` expression in *R*?

I'm trying to write the following (valid) statement in a more elegant (i.e. non-repetitive) way:

```
with(subset(mtcars, cyl > 4), {
  aggregate(subset(mtcars, cyl > 4),
            by=list(gear), min)
})
```

I'm aware of the following alternative syntax:

```
aggregate(mtcars[mtcars$cyl>4,], 
          by=list(mtcars[mtcars$cyl>4,'gear']), min)
```

I'm almost certainly sure someone came up with this problem before, but I'm lacking suitable words for web search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short version could be with the formula notation, with `.` meaning all other columns:

```r
aggregate(. ~ gear, data = subset(mtcars, cyl > 4), min)
```

Or with a pipe, which resembles `with`:

```r
subset(mtcars, cyl > 4) |>
  aggregate(. ~ gear, FUN = min)
```

Comment: Also `aggregate(. ~ gear, data = mtcars, subset = cyl > 4, min)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This syntax seems very helpful to me. I'm surprised that I've never come across it before.

Comment: One more: `aggregate(. ~ gear, data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl > 4, ], FUN = min)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be to use summarise() function using tidyverse family:

```
   mtcars |> filter(cyl > 4) |> group_by(gear) |> 
        summarise(across(everything(), .fns = min)) |> as.data.frame()

  gear  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am carb
1    3 10.4   6  225 105 2.76 3.215 15.41  0  0    1
2    4 17.8   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  0    4
3    5 15.0   6  145 175 3.54 2.770 14.50  0  1    4
```